# LINQ query with Left Join, Group by without null List

Tags: linq

I am working on LINQ query with Left-Join and groupBy, so I have list of questions which may or may not have answer collections. I want all the question group by question and their answer list, if it is null then don't want to add.

My current solution works fine but it still add a list with null where no answer is there hence giving me wrong result on Answer count()

```
var dhd = (from question in Context.Questions
                   join answer in Context.Answers on question.Id equals answer.QuestionId into ps
                   from answerDetail in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group answerDetail by question into grouped
                   select new
                   {
                       Question = grouped.Key,
                       Answer = grouped.ToList(),
                       //Answer = grouped.ToList() == null ? "(No Answer)" : grouped.Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                       TotalAnswerCount = grouped.Count()
                   }).ToList();
```

I have tried following script in above code and it throw null exception

```
    Answer = grouped.ToList() == null ? "(No Answer)" : grouped.Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `ps.DefaultIfEmpty()` it's making a list with null for non-matching element. If you want to get just null instead of a list with a null element, then try this code:

```
Answer = grouped.FirstOrDefault() == null ? null : grouped.ToList(),
```

If there's no match, then Answer is null, otherwise you get a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think issue occur because of type so try this one:

```
Answer = grouped.ToList() == null ? null : grouped.Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Comment: new Answer() doesn't recognise in code as above you have mention